# Determining if all messages are read within a thread MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Lets say you had a database schema that looked like this:

```
Message: (id: int PK, read: boolean, thread_id: int FK, ...)

Thread: (thread_id: int PK, ...)
```

in Message the read value represents if both parties have viewed the message.

How would you construct a query that returns every thread_id, and another value that represents if every message belonging to the thread has been read.
EG:
Messages:
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 0, 1),
(4, 1, 2),
(5, 1, 2),
(6, 1, 2)

Querying this would return as (read, thread_ID) => (0, 1), (1, 2)
Thread 1 has a read value of 0 because a single message was unread.
Thread 2 has a read value of 1 because every message was read.

How would you make this query?

Comment: can there be threads with no messages?

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for linking that to me. I'll use it in the future. ysth solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select thread_id, min(`read`) as `read` from message group by thread_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select min(m.read)
        from message m
        where m.thread_id = t.thread_id
       ) as flag
from thread t;
```

Note that a very similar method is:

```
select t.*,
       (not exists (select 1
                    from message m
                    where m.thread_id = t.thread_id and
                          not m.read
                   )
       ) as flag
from thread t;
```

Although this should be a wee bit faster with an index on `message(thread_id, read)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the BIT_AND() aggregation function. But it seems to be heavier than using MIN
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fNAh2VkpN9TeyDR7pqBCSR/1#